# How to manage services with Android MVI architecture

Tags: android, architecture

Currently, my project is built with MVI architecture principles but I'm getting confused when it comes to services.

I would like to write Unit tests to check logic of my Services(any class that implements `Service()`), currently I have separated this logic to be inside `ServiceInteractor` but it doesn't give me enough, I need additional layer.

I can't choose `Presenter` here because `Service` doesn't have any presentation layer. What could I use here? Maybe `useCases` would fit here to still follow MVI principles?